# Is listing tables in FROM clause essentially the same as an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Say I have these two tables:

```
User
===============
  UserID
  Username
  Job

UserInfo
===============
  UserID
  UserInfo1
  UserInfo2
```

are the following two sql statements the same (on Oracle 11g)?

```
SELECT * FROM User, UserInfo
WHERE UserInfo.UserID = User.UserID
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM User
INNER JOIN UserInfo ON UserInfo.UserID = User.UserID
```

Please explain/elaborate on the FROM [table list] syntax. I do not understand what's going on there...  If there are multiple UserInfos, will it return all of them? or just the first one that matches for each User? what about if the User doesnt have any UserInfo, will they be omitted from the results?

Comment: Yes both are same, first one is implicit join and other one is explicit

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate. I had trouble searching before I learned the correct terms.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Both of those queries are doing in INNER JOIN which will return all matching rows between both tables.

If your `user` table contains a single `UserId` but the `UserInfo` table contains, 4 rows with the same `userId`, then you will return 4 rows.  Since you have multiple rows that match you return *all* matching rows, not the first one.

If you want to return the `Users` that do not have a matching row in the `UserInfo` table, then you will have to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM User
LEFT JOIN UserInfo 
  ON UserInfo.UserID = User.UserID
```

The LEFT JOIN will return the rows that match in the `UserInfo` table as well as the unmatched rows.  The unmatched rows, will return a `null` for the `UserInfo` values.